# How to update another component state?

Tags: react-native, redux, state, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I have an editor for my app that contains several components like below:

- Buttons
- Cropper
- Page

All the components above are child of Editor page. So, What I need to do is update cropper zoom state from Buttons component. I have no problem when the state is used directly on UI component because I'm using **redux** for this case. But I'm struggling when I only need to update Buttons state.

Here is how I change the state from within the Buttons component:

```
this.setState({
            zoom: this.state.minZoom,
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
        });
```

How can I call above code from Cropper component?

Comment: Pass a callback down through the props, call it to send data back up, store shared state in the parent component instead of duplicating it. See [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from the React docs for an example.

Comment: @JoeClay So, I should remove "zoom" state from Cropper component and make "zoom" state on parent reducer?

Comment: If multiple components need to modify the `zoom` (and 'stay in sync'), then I would say it should either go in your `Editor` component's state (modify it with callback props) or in the Redux store (modify it with actions).

Answer (score 0):

Joe is right. Either store it in Editor's state or in redux store.

If you want to store it in Editor's state.

You can just pass a call as props in your Cropper component from Editor

```
<Cropper
  onChange={(minZoom) => {
     this.setState({
        zoom: minZoom,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
     })
  }}
/>
<Button zoom={this.state.zoom} />
```

then you can call it inside the Cropper component like this

```
this.props.onChange(this.state.minZoom);
```